# Create pthread that prints current time to command line

Tags: c, multithreading, time, pthreads

I have a command line program where I want to allow the user to print the current time using a separate thread.  I currently have it set up like this:

I get the user input, and then compare it to the string `time`.  If they are equal, I create a new thread that sets the time variable.

```
char currentTime[20];
if (strcmp(input, "time") == 0) {
    pthread_t thread;
    int rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, getTime, NULL);
    if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
    }
}
```

My `getTime` function:

```
void getTime() {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    sprintf(currentTime,"%s", asctime (timeinfo));
    printf("%s", currentTime);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I get an `Abort trap 6` error from this, but I don't get any errors from pthread, so I'm not sure what the issue is.  It seems like the thread is getting created properly.

Comment: Do you actually read anything into `input`? `void getTime() {` should be `void *getTime(void *arg) {` as required by `pthread_create()` even if you don't need to pass any arguments to the thread.

Comment: a `pthread` function has the signature of: `void * getTime( void * arg )`  so the first thing you need to do is correct your `getTime()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTime()` function returns nothing.

`currentTime` buffer is too short.

Try this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void * getTime( void * arg ) {
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;
   time ( &rawtime );
   timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
   printf("%s", asctime (timeinfo));
   return NULL;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
   pthread_t thread;
   int       rc = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, getTime, NULL );
   if (rc) {
      printf( "ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc );
      exit( -1 );
   }
   sleep( 1 );
   return 0;
}
```

Compile and execute it:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o timeThread timeThread.c -lpthread
$ ./timeThread 
Fri Feb 10 19:55:06 2017
$
```

The time is 25 character long.

Note the `sleep(1)` instruction to wait thread execution.